# Automatically configure the docker cloud in Jenkins using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm setting up Jenkins Docker Plugin using groovy script code from plugin website: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin
Everything working as desired, however the script deigned to create single docker cloud with single docker template. Of course, I can manually add new docker template into existing docker cloud, but I would like to make it work using groovy script. Or, alternatively if it possible to create single docker cloud with multiple docker templates using the same groovy script.

I tried add one more template by adding def DockerTemplateParameters and def dockerTemplateBaseParameters  templates into existing dockerCloud template with different value parameters, but script not working this way...

```
/*
   Automatically configure docker cloud stack in Jenkins.
   Docker plugin v1.1.5
*/

//configure cloud stack


import com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud
import com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate
import com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplateBase
import 
com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.launcher.AttachedDockerComputerLauncher
import io.jenkins.docker.connector.DockerComputerAttachConnector
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

// parameters

def dockerCloudParameters = [
name:             'Adas-Project-Server-18',
serverUrl:        'tcp://10.10.1.2:4243',
credentialsId:    '',
version:          '1.26',
connectTimeout:   5,
readTimeout:      15,
dockerHostname:   '',
containerCapStr:  '5' 
]

def DockerTemplateParameters = [
labelString:    'docker-adas-linux',
instanceCapStr: '1',
remoteFs:       '/var/lib/jenkins'
]

def dockerTemplateBaseParameters = [
image:              'adas-build:linux',
bindAllPorts:       false,
bindPorts:          '',
cpuShares:          null,
dnsString:          '',
dockerCommand:      '',
environmentsString: '',
extraHostsString:   '',
hostname:           '',
macAddress:         '',
memoryLimit:        null,
memorySwap:         null,
network:            '',
privileged:         true,
pullCredentialsId:  '',
sharedMemorySize:   null,
tty:                false,
volumesFromString:  '',
volumesString:      'media:/media 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CCACHE/Linux/.ccache/:/usr/src/.ccache'
]

// https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/docker-plugin- 
1.1.2/src/main/java/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/DockerTemplateBase.java
DockerTemplateBase dockerTemplateBase = new DockerTemplateBase(
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.image,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.pullCredentialsId,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.dnsString,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.network,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.dockerCommand,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.volumesString,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.volumesFromString,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.environmentsString,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.hostname,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.memoryLimit,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.memorySwap,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.cpuShares,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.sharedMemorySize,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.bindPorts,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.bindAllPorts,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.privileged,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.tty,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.macAddress,
dockerTemplateBaseParameters.extraHostsString
)

// https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/docker-plugin-1.1.2/src/main/java/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/DockerTemplate.java
DockerTemplate dockerTemplate = new DockerTemplate(
dockerTemplateBase,
new DockerComputerAttachConnector(),
DockerTemplateParameters.labelString,
DockerTemplateParameters.remoteFs,
DockerTemplateParameters.instanceCapStr
)

// https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/docker-plugin-1.1.2/src/main/java/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/DockerCloud.java
DockerCloud dockerCloud = new DockerCloud(
dockerCloudParameters.name,
[dockerTemplate],
dockerCloudParameters.serverUrl,
dockerCloudParameters.containerCapStr,
dockerCloudParameters.connectTimeout,
dockerCloudParameters.readTimeout,
dockerCloudParameters.credentialsId,
dockerCloudParameters.version,
dockerCloudParameters.dockerHostname
)

// get Jenkins instance
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()

// add cloud configuration to Jenkins
jenkins.clouds.add(dockerCloud)

// save current Jenkins state to disk
jenkins.save()
```

So far below what I've tried (still not working):

I've created cloud using above groove script. Now I'm trying add to it one more docker template using code from @Oliver Gondža suggestion:

```
/*
   Adding new docker template into existing docker cloud stack in Jenkins.
   Docker plugin v1.1.5
 */

//configure cloud stack


import com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate
import com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplateBase
import io.jenkins.docker.connector.DockerComputerAttachConnector
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

// parameters

def AndroidTemplateParameters = [
  labelString:    'docker-adas-android',
  instanceCapStr: '1',
  remoteFs:       '/var/lib/jenkins'
]

def AndroidTemplateBaseParameters = [
  image:              'yi/adas-build:android',
  bindAllPorts:       false,
  bindPorts:          '',
  cpuShares:          null,
  dnsString:          '',
  dockerCommand:      '',
  environmentsString: '',
  extraHostsString:   '',
  hostname:           '',
  macAddress:         '',
  memoryLimit:        null,
  memorySwap:         null,
  network:            '',
  privileged:         true,
  pullCredentialsId:  '',
  sharedMemorySize:   null,
  tty:                false,
  volumesFromString:  '',
  volumesString:      'media:/media /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CCACHE/Android/.ccache/:/usr/src/.ccache'
]

// https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/docker-plugin-1.1.2/src/main/java/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/DockerTemplateBase.java
DockerTemplateBase AndroidTemplateBase = new DockerTemplateBase(
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.image,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.pullCredentialsId,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.dnsString,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.network,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.dockerCommand,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.volumesString,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.volumesFromString,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.environmentsString,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.hostname,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.memoryLimit,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.memorySwap,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.cpuShares,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.sharedMemorySize,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.bindPorts,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.bindAllPorts,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.privileged,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.tty,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.macAddress,
  AndroidTemplateBaseParameters.extraHostsString
)

// get Jenkins instance
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()

def cloud = jenkins.clouds.getByName("Adas-Project-Server-18")
cloud.addTemplate(new DockerTemplate(
  AndroidTemplateBase,
  new DockerComputerAttachConnector(),
  AndroidTemplateParameters.labelString,
  AndroidTemplateParameters.remoteFs,
  AndroidTemplateParameters.instanceCapStr
))


// save current Jenkins state to disk
jenkins.save()
```

When I'm trying to run above code in Jenkins script console I'm getting following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method addTemplate() on
>   null object

Need help to fix this code and make it work.
Thank you in advance,
Igor.

Answer (score 1):

You can access configured clouds by `jenkins.clouds.getByName(String)` to locate the cloud you would like to update. You add more templates to it by calling `DockerCloud.addTemplate(DockerTemplate)`. Remember to save Jenkins once you are done. Roughly like this:

```java
DockerTemplateBase someOtherTemplateBase = new DockerTemplateBase(
    ...
)

def someOtherTemplateParameters = [
    ...
]

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def cloud = jenkins.clouds.getByName("Adas-Project-Server-18")
cloud.addTemplate(new DockerTemplate(
    someOtherDockerTemplateBase,
    new DockerComputerAttachConnector(),
    someOtherTemplateParameters.labelString,
    someOtherTemplateParameters.remoteFs,
    someOtherTemplateParameters.instanceCapStr
))
jenkins.save()
```

Comment: could you please give me an example how to implement your suggestion into my existing code? I'm still new to groovy language... Let's say I need add into existing `Adas-Project-Server-6`  dockerCloud  new template for android builds with `labelString:    'docker-adas-android'` Thank you in advance, Igor

Comment: I have attached an example code to get you started.

Comment: @ Oliver Gondža, the code you've provided, is separate code for adding new template into existing cloud or this code need to be integrated into my existing code? I'm still not able get it work...